# Microphone boost makes noise through headphones

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, noise

When my microphone boost is turned up (+30.0 dB), I can hear my recording clearly, but I hear a noise in my headphones, but when it's lowered (+20.0 dB) the noise is unnoticable, but I can barely hear my recording. Same is with VOIP (Skype, etc.)

What should I do?

Comment: is this microphone built into the computer (in/on the screen bezel etc) or is it a separate one plugged in via a mic-input and close to your mouth?

Comment: @Yorik It is a seperate microphone plugged in through the microphone jack, it is integrated into a webcam, so it can't be close to my mouth.